# Center Text in Header Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

i have something like this:

[image]

How to make the text of same height as the symbols ?

Logout and Fav should be beside the 'X' button.

Some code:

HTML:

```
<div  data-role="page" data-hash="false" id="companyPage" >
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
            <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
            <a onclick="logout()"  data-role="button"  data-transition="none" data-icon="delete">Logout</a>
            <a id="favpage"  onclick="getfav()" data-role="button" data-transition="none" data-icon="star">Fav</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-transition="none" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="companies" data-inset="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search Company..." data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d" data-filter-theme="d" data-divider-theme="b">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /content -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-header .ui-btn-inner  { font-size: 14px;  height:35px; padding: .6em 10px; min-width: .75em; }
```

Comment: could you share some code that you've used here ?

Comment: keep the symbol and text in a single element like `div`.

Comment: Either use `What's` answer or you can paste the corresponding html and css here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the line-height of the text to match the height of the button.

If the button is 30px high, and the text is in an `a` element, then your CSS would be:

```
a {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This works :-) I paste this in my css: .ui-header .ui-btn-inner  { line-height: 35px; display: block; font-size: 14px;  height:35px; padding: .6em 10px; min-width: .75em; }

Answer (score 1):

If this is the css for the buttons then:

```
.ui-header .ui-btn-inner  { 
        font-size: 14px;  
        height:35px; 
        padding: .6em 10px; /* here .6em = 12px */
        line-height:47px;
        min-width: .75em; 
}
```

so you can apply `line-height` value to this:`12px+height` that is `47px`

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your icons are defining the height of the buttons. If its true you should define the text height to be equal to the icons and then set the vertical-align to middle.

Comment: No, i define the height of the buttons. The icons themselves  have been placed correctly. But the text dont placed correctly.